# Помогите не запускается программа на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Вот код

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
import PyAudio

def talk(words):
print(words)
os.system("say " + words)

talk("Привет.Спроси у меня что-либо")

def command():
r = sr.Recognizer()



with sr.Microphone() as source:
     print ("Говорите,Владелец")
     r.pause_threshold = 1
     r.adjut_for_ambient_noice(source, duration=1)
     audio = r.listen(source)

try:
     zadanie = r.recognize_Yandex(audio).lower()
     print("Вы сказали:" + zadanie)
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    talk("Я вас поняла,но не совсем")
    zadanie = command()

return zadanie

def makeSomething(zadanie):
if  'open website' in zadanie:
    talk ("Подождите")
    url = 'https://web.roblox.com/home'
    webbrowser.open(url)
elif 'stop' in zadanie:
    talk("Заканчиваем")
    sys.exit()

while True:
makeSomething(command())
```

Ошибка:

> d:\Python>Python Phiton.py Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "Phiton.py", line 1, in  import speech_recognition as sr
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition' d:\Python>

Comment: А что значит не запускается? Ошибка? если да, то какая. Или может быть что-то еще. Тогда как именно вы запускаете этот код? Дополните вопрос пож. Кнопка править

Comment: d:\Python>Python Phiton.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Phiton.py", line 1, in <module>
    import speech_recognition as sr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'

d:\Python>

Comment: Я запускаю через командную строку

Comment: Вам надо скачать библиотеку `speech_recognition` . Подробнее [как скачать используя pip](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pip.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pip3 install --upgrade speechrecognition
```

Нуу, если установлен Python2

```
pip install --upgrade speechrecognition
```

Comment: Теперь я понял что у меня PyAudio не запускается

Comment: @BotKotik, пакет установлен?(pip install PyAudio)

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю то ошибка